# Does Marshal.AllocHGlobal create windows kernel handle?

Tags: c#, .net

We have windows service which consumes a lot of memory. It uses custom unmanaged structures allocated by calling Marshal.AllocHGlobal. These structures have been implemented several years ago by an unknown programmer. And of course today we have memory leaks. During the investigation of this problem, we notice that our unmanaged structures not always correctly are freed. We have fixed it, but one question has left: What if service crashes?

Does Marshal.AllocHGlobal create windows kernel handle?

As well as I know system has restricted number of handles and handles should be freed explicitly. If we don't free them, they would hang until system reboot. SafeHandle was created for garanteed freeing windows system handles like file descriptor. SafeHandle inherits from "magical" class CriticalFinalizerObject which changes GC behaviour: it guarantees finalization.

Should we inherits our structures from CriticalFinalizerObject?

Comment: What do you mean by "What if service fail?"?

Comment: For example what if service crashes with out of memory?

Comment: On any OS, if a process exits, all of its memory will be freed. So no worries

Comment: As well as I know system has restricted number of handles and handles should be freed explicitly. If we don't free them, they would hang until reboot. SafeHandle was created for garanteed freeing windows system handle like file descriptor. SafeHandle  derives "magical" class CriticalFinalizerObject which changes GC behaviour. It guarantees finalization.

Comment: `HGLOBAL` as well as other handles belong to your proces. When the process terminates everything is released and freed up. You should certainly use `SafeHandle` and similar tools to ensure that resources are cleaned up while your process executes. However, it has no effect on what happens when your process terminates where all resources are released back to the operating system (or you have found a leak in Windows).

Comment: The memory allocation functions actually do not operate in kernel mode for the most part, as an optimization; they manipulate the user-mode heap. Only when you allocate "large" blocks of memory (with an implementation-defined and undocumented limit, but it was 512K at one point) do they pass the request through to `VirtualAlloc`, which does go into kernel mode. In general, memory is not treated in quite the same way as other kernel objects. And in *all* cases, *all* handles of a process are freed when the process exits, and kernel objects cease to exist if all handles to them are closed.

Comment: In the Old Days (16-bit Windows and cooperative multitasking) it did use to be the case that processes could allocate stuff that wouldn't be properly freed when the process exited, as processes essentially shared the system. The Windows NT kernel, used in all flavors of Windows today, has always implemented proper separation of process resources. The reason finalization and cleanup exist is to ensure your process doesn't hog the system while running -- on exit the kernel will take care of its own (only things like kernel drivers can still gum things up).

Answer (score 0):

> Does Marshal.AllocHGlobal create windows kernel handle?

Yes, because [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=netframework-4.8):

> This method exposes the Win32 [LocalAlloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-localalloc?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function from Kernel32.dll.

So:

> Should we derive our structures from CriticalFinalizerObject?

No.

> As well as I know system has restricted number of handles and handles should be freed explicitly. If we don't free them, they would hang until system reboot.

False. Windows doesn't lose count of handles. When the process that requested the handles exits, its handles are freed.

> SafeHandle was created for garanteed freeing windows system handles like file descriptor. SafeHandle derives "magical" class CriticalFinalizerObject which changes GC behaviour: it guarantees finalization.

False. If your service crashes, how can its finalizers run?

Comment: According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.constrainedexecution.criticalfinalizerobject?view=netframework-4.8): In classes derived from the CriticalFinalizerObject class, the common language runtime (CLR) guarantees that all critical finalization code will be given the opportunity to execute, provided the finalizer follows the rules for a CER, even in situations where the CLR forcibly unloads an application domain or aborts a thread.

Comment: @user1770543: Sure, but not when a process is being terminated. Then it's game over even for the CLR.